# Magento Email templates, new shipment

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, shipment, shipment-email

I am new with Magento and I would like to configure new shipment emails, but I am having a problem with it.

I created a new email template like the one below:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<p>
    hi!
</p>
<p>
    tracking numbers {{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Magento_Sales::email/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}.
</p>
<p>
    end!
</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

and another one where the block variable is replaced with the following variable which are both suggested by magento:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_items" shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

and when I create a new shipment, I receive the email but the part where the block or layout is supposed to be, it is empty in the email.

Anyone knows what is wrong? Basically, I want to display all the tracking numbers (some shipments have 2 or more tracking numbers) of the specific shipment.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Have you check the log? Is there anything?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Hi, I do not have access to logs or the server, only in the admin side of magento. How can I get the tracking numbers in the shipment mail template? Thanks